# VBA - How to call SQL database connection from separate module

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have been digging on this but I couldn't find the solution related to it. I have a SQL database connection in a separate module (Module 5) that I wanted to call whenever I need to connect to my database from the other Module/form. This is for simplicity and single update so I don't need to go through every function to update the connection.

Database connection (Module5)

```vb
Function dbconnection()
Dim cnn As New ADODB.connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

cnn.Open = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=HOLAP- 
IST9985\CASETRACKER;Database=casetracker; Trusted_Connection=Yes"


cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing

End Function
```

And this is where I need to call the connection (Module2) - sends query to the database and displays result to my list box.

```vb
Function po_maintenance()

Dim cnn As New ADODB.connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset


rst.Open "SELECT * FROM po_numberstbl ORDER BY [PO_Number];", cnn, 
adOpenStatic
If rst.EOF = False Then
i = 0

With maintenance_frm.maintenance_list
.Clear
Do
    .AddItem
    .List(i, 0) = rst![po_number]
    .List(i, 1) = rst![purpose]
    .List(i, 2) = rst![Vendor]
    .List(i, 3) = rst![id]

    i = i + 1
    rst.MoveNext
Loop Until rst.EOF
End With
Else
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the connection from your function:

```vb
Function dbconnection() as ADODB.connection

    Dim cnn As New ADODB.connection

    cnn.Open = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=HOLAP-IST9985\CASETRACKER;" & _
               "Database=casetracker; Trusted_Connection=Yes"

    Set dbconnection = cnn

End Function
```

And then use it:

```vb
Function po_maintenance()

Dim cnn As New ADODB.connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

Set cnn = dbconnection()
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM po_numberstbl ORDER BY [PO_Number];", cnn, 
adOpenStatic
If rst.EOF = False Then
'etc etc
```

Comment: Hi Tim,

Thank you so much for your quick response. I am still having error with the code you provided but I was able to use the idea behind it and did some tweaks and it solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I have came up with to solve the connection problem..

dbconnection:

```vb
Public sqlt As String
Function dbconnection() As ADODB.connection
Dim cnn As New ADODB.connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

sqlt = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=HOLAP- 
IST9985\CASETRACKER;Database=storecons; Trusted_Connection=Yes"
End Function
```

Calling dbconnection:

```vb
Function po_maintenance()

Dim cnn As New ADODB.connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

Set cnn = Module5.dbconnection()
cnn.Open sqlt


rst.Open "SELECT * FROM po_numberstbl ORDER BY [PO_Number];", cnn, 
adOpenStatic
If rst.EOF = False Then
i = 0

With maintenance_frm.maintenance_list
.Clear
Do
    .AddItem
    .List(i, 0) = rst![po_number]
    .List(i, 1) = rst![purpose]
    .List(i, 2) = rst![Vendor]
    .List(i, 3) = rst![id]

    i = i + 1
    rst.MoveNext
Loop Until rst.EOF
End With
Else
End If
End Function
```